# Microsoft Graph API Query works on Explorer but not in Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a SharePoint Site, and inside a Documents folder, I have an Excel file.I want to make a specific Microsoft Graph call which gets the details of where the file resides. This works as expected when I test the query in Graph Explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/b8b6d734-2f94-4070-ae22-xxxxxxxxxxxx/drive/root
```

When I attempt to use the query in a console application using the Microsoft Graph .NET Client library, the test query executes fine:

```cs
var resultPage = await graphClient
  .Sites["b8b6d734-2f94-4070-ae22-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
  .Drive.Root
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

When I try to select a specific folder *inside* that root, it also works in Graph Explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/b8b6d734-2f94-4070-ae22-xxxxxxxxxxxx/drive/root/children/{foldername}/children/
```

But when I try this same query in my app, it get an error returned.

The code:

```
var resultPage = await graphClient
  .Sites["b8b6d734-2f94-4070-ae22-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
  .Drive
  .Root
  .Children["foldername"]
  .Children
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

The response:

```
Error getting events: 
  Code: itemNotFound
  Message: The resource could not be found.
```

I also tried using the folder's `id` instead of the but that also failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to use a path you need to use `ItemWithPath`:

```cs
var resultPage = await graphClient
  .Sites["b8b6d734-2f94-4070-ae22-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
  .Drive
  .Root
  .ItemWithPath("/{foldername}")
  .Children
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

You can also retrieve it via the DriveItem `id` like this:

```cs
var resultPage = await graphClient
  .Sites["b8b6d734-2f94-4070-ae22-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
  .Drive
  .Items["{item-id}"]
  .Children
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hey Marc thank you for your answer and the edit to my question! The question now became more helpful for other people to see and get help.

Comment: Sadly I tried both of your solutions and the query still doesn't work :/ It returns "itemNotFound". I want the file inside the folder "automated-reports" as shown in this link: https://ibb.co/Jkq1jCW

Comment: Is the drive the default document library? You may need to specify the drive `.Drives["drive id"].Items["item id"]`.